# Can return two arrays in struct but not in class C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I can return two arrays by 'struct' with below codes; but can't translate the code to "class". the "class" code and error areattached also.

please shed lights on it. I have to use "class" and mutiple arrays in my project.

1) with "struct"

```
   struct strA{
   int *p;
   int *p1;
   };

   strA setValue(int n)
   {
     strA strB;
     strB.p=new int[n];
     strB.p1=new int[n];

      for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
      {
            strB.p[i]=i;
            strB.p1[i]=i*2;
      }
      return strB;
   }

   int main(){
      const int N=3;
      strA strC;
      strC=setValue (5);
      for (int i=0; i<N;i++)
      {
            cout<< strC.p[i]<<endl;
            cout<< strC.p1[i]<<endl;
      }
      return 0;
   }
```

2. with "class". it turned out "error C3867: 'strA::setValue': function call missing argument list; use '&strA::setValue' to create a pointer to member"

   ```
   class strA{
   public:
     int *p;
     int *p1;
   public:
     strA();
     ~strA(){delete p, delete p1;}
     strA setValue(int n);
   };


    strA strA::setValue(int n)
    {
      strA strB;
      strB.p=new int[n];
      strB.p1=new int[n];  
      for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
      {
           strB.p[i]=i;
           strB.p1[i]=i*2;
      }
      return strB;
     }

    int main(){
       const int N=3;
       strA strC;
       strC.setValue (N);
       for (int i=0; i<N;i++)
       {
         cout<< strC.setValue<<endl;
         cout<< strC.p1[i]<<endl;
       }
       return 0;
       }
   ```

Comment: `struct` and `class` are just two different keywords used to declare a class. C++ has no structs and classes, but just classes. The only difference between `struct` and `class` is their default acces (private for `class` and public for `struct`)

Comment: please format your code properly. I dont want to do it myself, because there are typos in it and I dont want to fix them or make it worse...

Comment: This line seams strange : ` cout<< strC.setValue<<endl;` => `setValue` is a function

Comment: your code violates the Rule of 3/5/0 probably resulting in double delete

Comment: your implementation of  `setValue` looks odd (in both versions of the code) you create a temporary set its values and then return it, instead `setValue` should set the values of `this` object

Comment: btw using the same naming for types and instances is very bad for readability

Comment: Sorry. a few code lines in "class"  portion is not nicely formatted. My apology.

Comment: `~strA(){delete p, delete p1;}` this might do the correct thing, but at least it looks fishy. Read about the comma operator and prefer `delete p; delete p1;`

Comment: I will repost my questions

Comment: why repost? this one isnt too bad, just add the line where the error occurs and then it should be fine

Comment: @MosheBinieli that code shouldnt even be a temporary solution, it doesnt follow one of the most basic rules of OO in C++, you still can delete the comment ;)

Comment: @MosheBinieli you'd have to write a copy constructor, or better dont use raw arrays but `std::vector` and follow the rule of 0

Comment: The problems are that you can not "cout" the function name "setValue", another fix that I would recommend is at the function "setValue", instead of returning new instance you can just modify the current instance by using "this" keyword in C++.

This is the example code from peastbin: https://pastebin.com/krusLaLn

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but terminology matters. These objects do not contain arrays. They contain **pointers**. Each pointer points at the first element of an array. So the code does **not** return two arrays; it returns two **pointers** that point to arrays. Don't blur the distinction between pointers and arrays. It's blurry enough in normal code, where the name of an array usually decays into a pointer to its first element. If you add to the blurring you'll just make things even more confusing. An array is not a pointer and a pointer is not an array.

Comment: Thank you so much. your code is clear and solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, As the answer of P.W. You will meet a compile error in this line
`cout<< strC.setValue<<endl;` because you forgot to pass argument for the function `setValue(int n)`.

Second, it is not suitable idea to write `setValue(int n)` function as what you have written. I recommend to you to write the function as following:

```
void ::setValue(int n)
{
  this->p=new int[n];
  this->p1=new int[n];  
  for (int i=0; i<n;i++)
  {
    this->p[i]=i;
    this->p1[i]=i*2;
  }
}
```

I think you are newbie and you should read more about Object Oriented Programming.

Comment: Thank all of you. I am in progress learning C++. Just read online on "this" pointer topic after seeing your codes. With your helps, I feel better as the support is there for me to progress and improve.

Answer (score 2):

I will first address the error you have mentioned. There are other issues with this code as well.

The error is because of this line in main:

```
cout<< strC.setValue<<endl;
```

`setValue` is a function and it has to be called with arguments like this:

```
strC.setValue(N);
```

Other issues:

1. You cannot use `cout` to print the object returned from `setValue`
   unless you have overloaded the `<<` operator for the class `strA`.
2. In the `setValue` function you have defined an object `strB` and you assign memory to its members. This memory is not freed. What you are freeing are the members of the object `strC` defined in `main`. Look at the destructor of `strA` and you will understand.

The `main` in the first ("struct") version of the code can be used in the second ("class") version because `p` and `p1` are public.